# How to add a new theme in Magento2.1.5?

Tags: magento2.1.5

How to add a new theme? I am trying to add in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at magento docs for info http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

Comment: another one help,i need to deploy my theme into magento,already placed the theme files into root files

Comment: i have seen lot of deploy comments some have i found some result and i am tried like this D:\wamp\www\Magentonew>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy in CMD but ended with error-'php' is not  recognized as an internal or external error

Answer (score 1):

Like @Martins said: The official Magento documentation can help you.

Also, look at the default blank/luma themes. Looking at 'how Magento does it' is always very insightful on how you can achieve similar results yourself.